# Import a header from a referenced (blue) folder in Xcode

Tags: xcode, build, import, reference

Sorry to post a similar question to what's already here, but none of those solutions worked.

Scenario:
- I drag a folder A (which contains another folder B and then the settings.h file I want to import) from Finder into my Xcode project.

- I set that folder to create references (thereby making this folder blue in the left-hand pane in Xcode)
- I want to import a header file, settings.h

How do I do this?  I've tried everything.  Add $(PROJECT_HOME)/FolderA/** to user header search paths, $(PROJECT_HOME)/FolderA/FolderB, etc.

I've tried

```
#import "./FolderA/FolderB/settings.h"
#import "settings.h"
```

etc. etc.

The only thing that works is the absolute path on my harddrive, which of course isn't useful because then you can't work on another machine without having to change settings.

I'm pulling my hair out because all the suggestions up until now have made sense, but unfortunately don't work.